# web api login and password query string formation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have generated the WebApi, it contain method to login using login and password.
I cannot access the query string.

This link i already tried.but not get a result.it showing error.
`http://localhost:58940/api/Login?loginName=AAA&password=123`

Api controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetLoginId(string loginName, string password)
{
     LoginService loginSvc = new LoginService();
     var res = loginSvc.GetLoginId(loginName,password);
     if (res != null)
     {
         return Ok(res);
     }
     return NotFound();
}
```

In debug procees (debugger) controller code only executes, but not go to service,unitofwork,repository files in visual studio.

Comment: You will have to inject the LoginService to the controller constructor to access it from GetLoginId http method.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This query string is not working. Url not loaded. No error on web api.